# I want timestamp in following format "2020-06-04T07:37:19.2623962Z"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timestamp, format

I want timestamp in following format "2020-06-04T07:37:19.2623962Z", i am working on angular.

Comment: And the problem/question is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: JavaScript datetime does not have such a high precision. Milliseconds is the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this looks like the ISO format, this is part of the Date object in javascript. If you are using it you could simply write

```
new Date().toISOString();
```